# Is there a formal mathematical name for the geometry of a circle, sphere, etc, regardless of dimension?

Tags: geometry, terminology

In geometry of 2D and 3D, it's not uncommon for people to call a square or rectangle a `Box` in the field I work in. This makes naming things easier since it's clear what's in a folder of 'boxes'.

Does the similar name exist for a circle and a sphere? Interestingly we have circles in 3D that could be defined as the intersection of a geometric primitive with a sphere, like a plane slicing through a sphere to form a circle. However searching for a unifying name (even if it's not that good of a name) has been unfruitful.

Does a name exist for this classification? As in, a name for circular or spherical objects defined by some distance from (for convenience here) the origin?

Some things seem easy, like a hyperplane is going down a dimension, so it ends up working for almost any dimension. I was hoping there was something like this that would either work for 2 and 3 dimensions, or better, work for N dimensions.

Comment: Comic sections is a contender.

Comment: In metric spaces, the words ball and sphere are used

Comment: How about a ball?

Comment: In metric spaces/topology, balls or neighbourhoods are defined in this way

Answer (score 6):

We often refer to an "$n$-sphere", usually to say $S^{1}$ is a circle and $S^2$ is the surface of an ordinary sphere.  An $n$-sphere sits in $R^{n+1}$.  I sometimes see hypersphere used, but that is less common.

If you want to include the interior, the term is "$n$-ball".

By the way, the generic word for "length, area, volume" etc. is *content*.

Comment: I there a notation for the n-ball, other than $B(0,1)$ where the dimension figures explicitely ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Wikipedia doesn't seem to have one either.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general geometric framework called the "space of spheres" covering spheres in any dimension, in particular

- ordinary circles for dimension 2 or even
- line segments $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ for dimension 1.

The important fact is that these spaces are endowed with a quadratic form that I am going to explain in the case of circles, but that can be extended to any dimension.

As a circle can be defined by kinds of equations:

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2 \ \ \iff \ \ x^2+y^2-2ax-2by+c=0\tag{1}$$

we will consider that a circle is defined by coordinates $(a,b,c)$.

Due to the equivalence in (1), we have

$$R^2=a^2+b^2-c>0\tag{2}$$

The "set of circles" can be considered as a kind of 3D space deprived of the interior of a certain paraboloid.

Moreover, the RHS of (2) will give a kind of "norm" (please note the double quotes) for a circle:

$$\|(a,b,c)\|^2=a^2+b^2-c\tag{3}$$

or, introducing a 4th (projective) dimension $d$ for the homogeneization of expression (3).

$$\|(a,b,c)\|^2=a^2+b^2-cd=a^2+b^2+\tfrac12(c-d)^2-\tfrac12(c+d)^2$$

which is a true quadratic form with signature $(+,+,+,-)$ (Minkovski space structure)

For more about this space, see first my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3640023), then the very nice article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266349529_Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulations_and_Voronoi_diagrams_made_practical/figures?lo=1) showing application to Voronoi tessellations and Voronoi triangulations.

For more, see the paragraph "Space of spheres" in the marvellous book "Geometry II" of Marcel BERGER (Springer, 1987).